# Apply raw formatting only to epilog, not to parser and argument group descriptions

Tags: python, argparse

I've defined my program's command-line interface with `argparse`, and I would like to provide some examples via the epilog. By default, the `argparse` module strips extra whitespace, wraps the description texts, etc. This default behavior is very useful for the program's description and for the argument group descriptions, but for the epilog I would like to provide a pre-formatted string that the parser should not modify. If I specify `formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`, this gives the desired behavior for the epilog, but I lose the default behavior I rely on for the program and argument group descriptions. I can go back and manually fix the wrapping of these descriptions, but it's tedious.

Is there a way to apply the raw formatting ***only*** to the epilog?

Answer (score 0):

This formatter changes one method, `_fill_text`:

```
class RawDescriptionHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    ....
    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        return ''.join(indent + line for line in text.splitlines(keepends=True))
```

This handles wrap for anything that's defined as `text` in the `format_help` method

```
def format_help(self):
    formatter = self._get_formatter()

    # usage
    formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                        self._mutually_exclusive_groups)

    # description
    formatter.add_text(self.description)

    # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
    for action_group in self._action_groups:
        formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
        formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
        formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
        formatter.end_section()

    # epilog
    formatter.add_text(self.epilog)

    # determine help from format above
    return formatter.format_help()
```

That is, the `description`, the `group.description` and the `epilog`.

I can imagine creating an alternative Formatter subclass that only changes the wrapping of the epilog (maybe identified by some key word).  But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)